# Manipulating files in Python with non-ascii character file names (emojis)

Tags: python

I have an IFTTT Integration that pulls images from a subreddit into a dropbox on my PC. The way it works it that the file name is the title of the Reddit post. This means that there are a lot of non-ascii characters in the names, such as emojis and other characters, and sometimes very long names that are over the max file name size. I am attempting to check the modified time of all the files in that directory and delete files that are over x hours old using Python 2.7.

I have worked out a way to get the long file names by prefixing the file path with `\\?\` which tells windows to allow long file names. However, now I am stuck on another problem, trying to os.stat on files that have the emoji's.

Example file names:

```
❤️❤️❤️
A selfie with my little queen ❤️
Our beautiful Lily, aged ~12. Short on teeth, podgy, gets crap caught in her fur and I think she’s going deaf but we wouldn’t have her any other way. She’s mellowed out a lot in her old age but will still run around the house at 2am.
```

Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, time, os, time

MediaPath = sys.argv[1]
cleanup = sys.argv[2]

now = time.time()
for media in os.listdir(MediaPath):
    mediaFile = os.path.join(MediaPath, media)
    fileTime = os.stat("\\\\?\\" + mediaFile).st_mtime
    #preferred deletion time in hours times 60 mins times 60 seconds to get seconds

    if fileTime < now - int(cleanup) * 60 * 60:
        if os.path.isfile(mediaFile):
            os.remove(mediaFile)
            print("Media removed: " + mediaFile)
    else:
        print("Media NOT removed: " + mediaFile)
```

I am passing in 2 arguments, the path for the files and the cleanup time in hours.

I get an error: `WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\USER\\Pictures\\aww\\A selfile with my little queen ??.jpg'`

Comment: When you run `dir` in that directory, how does the file name with selfies show up?

Comment: Also try setting the Windows command prompt character page to Unicode at the beginning of your program. Might help. `os.system(“chcp 65001”)`

Comment: @jdaz "06/18/2020  05:03 AM           592,432 A selfie with my little queen ❤️.jpg"
However in CMD it shows 2 squares with ? in them instead of the emoji, but when i pasted it here it converted it to the emoji.

Setting os.system(“chcp 65001”) still produces the same error.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the fact that the heart emoji takes up 2 characters?